# Retrieve Humar Tasks list assigned to group in jBPM

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

We are interacting with jBPM6 from Java using REST API, using GetTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner we can get the tasks lists assigned to the particular user but our requirement is that we need to get all the tasks assigned to a group which we are not able to.
Is there any API which we can use to achieve this results or any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

when you are logged to the REST APIs you only have access to the tasks assigned to the logged user or to the groups where the user belong. Then you can differentiate using the status of the task to know if it is a group task (Ready status -> needs to be claimed) or a already assigned personal task.

Comment: thanks, but let me give you an example so i can communicate my requirements better. Lets say we have 5 tasks and out of these tasks 2 tasks are still not assigned to anybody but remaining 3 tasks are picked by 3 different user (from the same group lets say User A, User B and User C) so when any user from same group opens his/her dashboard he/she should get displayed that 3 tasks are assigned to User A, User B and User C.